# Access private logger in parent class

Tags: java

I have the following class which I can't modify:

```
public class StorageRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageRepository.class);

}
```

I have to use this class:

```
public class SecRepository extends StorageRepository {

   LOGGER.error(.....);

}
```

The parent class can't be modified because it it's in a private jar.

What are the options to solve the error: `LOGGER' has private access in 'com.StorageRepository'`

Comment: Define and use a dedicated logger for the `SecRepository` class. It's not clear why you're trying to use `StorageRepository`'s.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the same `Logger`, just use

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageRepository.class);
```

in `SecRepository`, and it will retrieve the same `Logger` instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using reflection:

```
public Logger getLogger() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field f = StorageRepository.class.getDeclaredField("LOGGER");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return (Logger) f.get(null);
}
```

Comment: ... which you probably should not do.